# Data normalization

Tags: statistics, normalization, business-intelligence

I am very new at BI and BD but want to have some directions on the following. 
When I want to classify "good" or "best" links then I could use like counts from Facebook or retweet counts from twitter. 
But some communities have large user bases so their links get much more likes or retweets. How can I "normalize" these huge community likes with for example the likes of a similar news item link of a much smaller community who have much lesser like count?

Is this called normalizing by the way? And in what kind of books can i learn these kinds of algorithms about "quality" (in this case of an article for example)? What is it called anyhow what I am trying to do?

Thnx.

Comment: You can do this normalization in a variety of ways, depending on the task and the available data.

Comment: In what kind of books can I learn the basics of normalizations then? I searched on amazon for normalization but did not have correct results.

Comment: Database normalization is more about the table structures of your database. Not sure if that is what you seeking.

Comment: Database normalization or database design might yield better results. B.T.W. this a very broad question maybe even a discussion question and those type of questions are less suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: This is not about database normalization at all, it's about statistics.

Comment: Yeah statistics whas the first thing i did think about. Bu a book about statistics won't give a lot of insight about my question right?

Comment: Do you want to do a statical analysis on the basis of the number of links corrected for user base?

Comment: Yes exactly, nice recapitulated Mr. Radical!

Comment: A multi regression analysis comes to mind. Something like: quality of link = alfa + B1*Number_of_links + B2*User_base + error term. However, how to determine the parameters would be a challenge. You could use historical data (number_of_links; user_base; quality of link), but then need to determine a way to determine the independent variable (quality of link).

Comment: That looks like 4 variables to determine, right? Is z-score a good alternative for my purpose?

Comment: You have 2 dependent variables (number_of_links and user_base). The other variable is the independent variable quality_of_link. The betas are the parameters you need to determine. You need an objective way to determine the quality_of_link. Then you use a statical test to estimate the parameters for your model. For example, to determine the price of a house: price house = alfa + beta 1 * number of square feet + beta 2 * number of rooms. You can estimate the values of the parameters by running regressions. You could do this in a statical program

Comment: The z-score, t-test or p-value have to do with the rejection region of a hypothesis. For you model you could use that to determine if the variables are significant.

Comment: Mr. Radical do you know a good book what explains all of these kinds of aspects of statistics. A feel very noob on this subject.

Comment: @Geveze A general statistics introduction book for bachelor level course will do just fine. You know z-score already, so my guess is that you have some knowledge from statistics. Or try to search online for linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could try this linear regression:

Quality_of_link = alfa + B1*Number_of_links + B2*User_base + error term.

To determine parameters (B1 and B2) for Dependent Variables (Number_of_links, User_base) you could use historical data (number_of_links; user_base; quality of link) and estimate the values of the parameters by running a linear regressions. You could do this in a statical program. Good statical programs include R-project and SPSS.

Important in this respect is the objective way to determine the Quality_of_link. I think you could do a test by rating a number of links, preferable by the targeted audience of you site. Then use the average value given on a scale (e.g. 0-100) to the links.

After you have run the regression in you test phase your can use it in you final model. This would then be:  Quality_of_link = alfa + B1*Number_of_links + B2*User_base. You could then use say above a Quility_of_link above 70 is a good link and higher than 90 best link.

For good textbooks it will be difficult to point you to a particular book which I haven't read myself. I would first recommend using the knowledge you already have an use the internet if some knowledge needs to be refreshed.

Hope this helps. Success with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called Normalization or Standardization.

You could calculate the [Z-Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)† of the number of "likes" of an article, so that the comparison is fair. The Z-Score is the number of standard deviations that a value is above the mean.

You can probably get some better advice on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Good luck!

† If you are sampling, you should use the T-statistic instead.

Comment: If I would use z-score for normalization and give a weight to each website like "quality = weight * z-score". This works great for the positive number of z-scores. But on the negative z-score values this is not working and even make it worse. Is there a solution for this negative z-score value?

Comment: You might have to re-standardize your z-scores to be between 0 and 1 in this case then.